# Mac OSX Cataline not rebooting when cannot connect to wifi

Tags: macos, wifi, catalina

Several times I have had the experience that my Macbook Pro (13 inch, 2017, v10.15.5) will not reboot completely. The white progress bar gets very close to complete and then stalls.

Each time this happened I was having wifi connection problems.  The way I solve it is to reboot in safe mode, connect to the wifi, and then reboot.  When it first happened I took the Mac to the Apple store and they replaced the wifi hardware and the logic board. But it still continues to happen.

Is there a setting/fix that will stop this behaviour?

Comment: Not sure if it affects recent Macs, but I've heard that having the wifi configured for IPv6 on older Macs can stall the Mac on reboot. You might have to reboot your Mac when you're out of range of your wifi point, and go into `System preferences` > `Network` > `Wifi` > `Advanced` > `TCP/IP` and set IPv6 to configure manually. Again not sure if this will help, but worth a try?

Comment: It is currently set to configure IPv6 automatically, so it is possible this is the problem. I will try it when I get a chance.